# CVs: How should I include papers that have been accepted as abstract submissions to a journal, but still need to go through manuscript review?

Tags: cv

To be specific, I've submitted an extended abstract to a special issue of an education journal (I'm a graduate student in STEM). Based on the reviews of that abstract, we've been asked to submit a manuscript in a few months.

This is certainly "acceptance" of some sort, but I'm wary of overstating this on my CV as there's still a chance they could reject in the manuscript review. However, as this paper is super relevant to an award nomination I need to submit my CV for, I'd really like to have it on there somehow.

How can I best note this on my CV?

(While [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/7549/should-i-post-publications-in-preparation-or-just-submitted-on-my-cv) and [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/49727/accepted-subject-to-minor-revisions-how-should-i-list-this-in-my-cv) are close to my situation, they're referring more to paper manuscripts that have been accepted with some contingency.)

Comment: You could make a preprint available. Or you could cite it as "under submission." I favour the former, because if it is rejected, then you'll never need to acknowledge the rejection.

Comment: @user2768 -- would this be understood by a reader as something different than "submitted to"? Candidly, I don't think anyone besides my advisor would ever see multiple rounds of my CV deeply enough to notice if it has to be taken off at a later date (again, I think there's only a low chance of this, but still...). I currently have it as "submitted to" but was looking for an option that acknowledges that it's passed one round of gatekeepers...

Comment: A preprint needn't be under submission nor previously submitted, so the two cases are different. I hadn't considered different versions of your CV being a problem. I was thinking that your CV might get you an interview and at interview you might be asked about your submission, at which point you might be forced to acknowledge a rejection. By comparison, if you're asked about a preprint, then you could explain that it has now been accepted for publication.

Comment: What discipline?

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, you should try to to be as candid as possible and simply state exactly what the state of the paper is. In this case, you could for example write, "extended abstract accepted - awaiting full manuscript submission" or something similar to that.